# Scala setting Type on parameter in a method invocation

Tags: scala, methods, parameters

I have a typo (because I didn't mean it to be there) in my scala code, and can't quite work out if its benign.

[image]

On line `84` - does scala just allow that `:Long` to let me remind myself what type the parameter is?
Is it in any way different to not setting the type when passing it into a parameter?

My in-depth testing seems to show line 83 and 84 behave the same

Comment: Please, post your code, not a photograph of your code. We want to read it, copy&paste it, and debug it, not critique its use of color and perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type ascription on an expression can introduce an implicit conversion, so it is not necessarily benign in general. It has no effect in your example. Also, if the method is overloaded, you might select a different overload.

Comment: ahhh `type ascription` them be the key search key words. As Plato said; give me the correct search key word, and I will return knowledge. Or was that google?

Comment: "Give me a search term long enough and I will move the world."

Answer (score 1):

> does scala just allow that :Long to let me remind myself what type the parameter is?

No, it isn't limited to method parameters at all. You can write `: SomeType` after any expression (parentheses may be necessary). You can think of it as similar to

```
val iAmLong1: Long = iAmLong
callMe(iAmLong1)
```

In general it can be used to help type inference, or, as som-snytt's answer mentions, to trigger an implicit conversion.